# WildFlyでシステムプロパティを取得する方法

Tags: wildfly

XXX.warフォルダをWildFlyに登録してWebブラウザに画面を表示させています。
特定のボタンを押したときにdoPostが実行されるのですがこの時にシステムプロパティの値を取得したいのですが
どこで設定すればいいのでしょうか？

OS:Linux Sever7.8
WildFly:18.0.1

Answer (score 0):

`standalone/configuration/standalone.xml` に記述します:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:10.0">
    <system-properties>
        <property name="foo" value="bar"/>
        <property name="hoge" value="piyo"/>
    </system-properties>

    <!-- ... -->
</server>
```

参考:

- [2.3.7. Basic structure of the management resource trees](https://docs.wildfly.org/18/Admin_Guide.html#basic-structure-of-the-management-resource-trees)
- [14.1.1. Adding, reading and removing system property using CLI](https://docs.wildfly.org/18/Admin_Guide.html#adding-reading-and-removing-system-property-using-cli)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
システムプロパティの値を取得することができました。